# Как реализовать Метод Ньютона  на C#?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Помогите разобраться с методом Ньютона для поиска корней функции.

Comment: Если правильно тебя понял, то вот две ссылки: [Раз](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=79541&zep=RootFindingDemo%2fRootFinding.cs&rzp=%2fKB%2frecipes%2fRootFinding%2f%2fRootFinding_src.zip) и [Два](http://numerical.codeplex.com/). А вообще гугл дает достаточно обширные результаты по реализации этого на C# и на других языках.

Comment: Надо просто вникнуть в [описание](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) метода и согласно ему реализовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод Ньютона (метод касательных) - итерационный метод. Может применяться для нахождения корней функций типа f(x) = 0;

1. Находим грубое приближение корня X0.
2. Вычисляем поправку к значению X0: Dx = -f(X0)/f'(X0).
3. Новое значение X1 = X0 + Dx.
4. Проверка условия f(X1) = 0.
5. Если не удовлетворены, идем на шаг 2, но уже с x = X1.

-

```
// Вычисление квадратного корня из P с погрешностью е при начальном приближении x0.
#include <math.h>
double sqrt(const double P, const double e, const double x0)
{
  double x = x0; // Шаг 1
  while(1)        
  {
    double f = x * x - P;
    if(fabs(f) < e) // Шаги 4, 5
      break;
    double dx = -f / (2.0 * x) // Шаг 2
    x += dx; // Шаг 3.
  }
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Описание есть в начале книги SICP. Если правильно помню, то в разделе про рекурсию.

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.